# What do I use to fill in low spots in my yard?

Tags: soil

I have low spots in my yard that I would like to slowly fill in.  This isn't anything big enough to constitute a truck load of dirt or anything. What can I use (either dirt or manure) to fix these spots?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dirt can mean pretty much anything, from good to poor quality soil.

Manure "generally" refers to a natural fertiliser and is good for working into soil, adds organic matter, helps open up the soil... It's not the best material for filling in low spots.

Personally I would use a 50-50 mix of "high quality" screened (¼inch/6.25mm sieved) top soil & compost for filling in low spots in a garden, or lawn.

- "High quality" = Make your own from compost and soil (materials) you control, or buy from a local independently owned garden nursery, or if you're lucky enough to have access to a local (free) community composting facility that is known to output good quality material.

  - Basically you want to reduce the risk as much as possible of bringing in lots! of weed seeds into your environment.

If filling in low spots on a lawn, I would fill to a depth of no more than 1inch (25mm) at a time and would fill in no more than twice a year, once in early to mid Spring and once in early Autumn (Fall).

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the timing suggestions as well... I probably mess up "when" to do stuff in my yard as often as "how"

Answer (score 9):

The benefit of "dirt" is that it won't settle as much as manure, so you won't need to keep adding to it. But, depending on what "dirt" you use, it may be lacking in organic matter and nutrients. If you're buying commercial bagged soil, check the label to see what it has in terms of organic matter and fertilizer.

The benefit of cow manure is that it will provide those areas with lots of organic matter and nutrients. Horse manure has the same benefit, but comes with the problem that it can contain a lot of weed seeds.

Depending on where you live, soil and/or manure might be free for the hauling. If you have the choice of poor quality soil and manure, take a little of both and mix them. In my case, I have lots of free manure and not much soil, so I tend to fill low spots with manure. When they settle I add a little more.

Answer (score 2):

Use [coco peat](http://landscapeandgardenblogs.wordpress.com/2013/08/29/get-a-better-yield-from-your-plants-using-coco-peat/) - It's an organic soil derived from coconut husks for garden vegetables and plants which is Eco-friendly. It has many benefits with long lasting good effects.

**Benefits of using coco Peat in Garden Soil:**

1. It holds water for a longer time
2. Provide required ingredients to vegetables and plants
3. Maintain soil pH
4. Maintain low salt in soil which is more beneficial for better plant growth
5. No fertilizers required