# What are the different ways you can level a yard?

Tags: lawn, lawn-repair

Our new house has a backyard that's very pretty "bumpy" and not very level.  What are our options for leveling it?

Comment: similar to http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/how-to-fill-low-spots-over-existing-grass-in-my-yard

Comment: I spent a summer just constantly mowing a yard that was pretty bumpy, enough to roll an ankle a few times. If it gets enough sunlight and you mulch it everytime, it won't be flat by the end of summer, but it's cheap and easy, and an improvement